# Why lucene boosted query has lower score than same normal query?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I'm testing boost operator in lucene and found strange behaviour

**Example**

1. query1 = `"red fox"`
2. query2 = `"red^1.2 fox"`

When I test queries against text:

> "wonderful red fox"

I got score for query2 lower than for query1. But I expect that query2 should win.

Below explanations for queries

**Explain for query1**

```
{0,4339554 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0,2169777 = (MATCH) weight(content:fox in 0), product of:
    0,7071068 = queryWeight(content:fox), product of:
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      2,304384 = queryNorm
    0,3068528 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:fox in 0), product of:
      1 = tf(termFreq(content:fox)=1)
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      1 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=0)
  0,2169777 = (MATCH) weight(content:red in 0), product of:
    0,7071068 = queryWeight(content:red), product of:
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      2,304384 = queryNorm
    0,3068528 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:red in 0), product of:
      1 = tf(termFreq(content:red)=1)
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      1 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=0)
}
```

**Explain for query2**

```
{0,4313012 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0,2396118 = (MATCH) weight(content:fox^1.25 in 0), product of:
    0,7808688 = queryWeight(content:fox^1.25), product of:
      1,25 = boost
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      2,035813 = queryNorm
    0,3068528 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:fox in 0), product of:
      1 = tf(termFreq(content:fox)=1)
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      1 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=0)
  0,1916894 = (MATCH) weight(content:red in 0), product of:
    0,6246951 = queryWeight(content:red), product of:
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      2,035813 = queryNorm
    0,3068528 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:red in 0), product of:
      1 = tf(termFreq(content:red)=1)
      0,3068528 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
      1 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=0)
}
```

I wonder why boosted query has lower score than normal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the query norm.  This feature of the scoring algorithm attempts to make scores *roughly* comparable from one query to the next.

This is calculated as:

> queryNorm = 1 / sumOfSquaredWeights<sup>½</sup>

Where:

> sumOfSquaredWeights   =   query boost<sup>2</sup> · ∑ ( idf · term boost )<sup>2</sup>

If you remove that factor from the explanations, simply by dividing the final score by the query norm, you find that the second query does, indeed, get a higher score:

- query1 --> .4339554 / 2.304384 = *0.1883*
- query2 --> .4313012 / 2.035813 = *0.2119*

The larger point though: You shouldn't read too much into comparing the scores from one query to the next. Scores are only really relevant to the query that generated them. You can see in the explanations that the boosted term contributes a greater *relative* weight to the score, which is all boosts are really intended to do.

Comment: So how could I achive desired behaviour. I need `query2` be a winner (`query2` score should be higher than `query1`). I've overrided method `DefaultSimilarity.QueryNorm` to always return `1.0` to ignore query norm. Does it make sence?

Comment: @user854301 - Sure, that will effectively disable the queryNorm, but whatever you are trying to accomplish by comparing them is almost certainly a bad idea. Scores aren't meaningful when taken out of the context of the query. I'd strongly recommend you rethink whatever it is you are trying to do. See: [Scores as Percentages](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages).